# Codemagic build fais for iOS app with Notification Extension

Tags: ios, flutter, provisioning-profile, onesignal, codemagic

There is some problem that don't let me build iOS app with Notification Extension on Codemagic.
I have Apple Push Services certificate and 2 separate provisioning profiles - first for app and second for Notification Extension.
Code signing method is switched to manual.

> ❌  error: No certificate for team '********' matching 'Apple Push
>   Services' found: Select a different signing certificate for
>   CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY, a team that matches your selected certificate, or
>   switch to automatic provisioning. (in target 'Runner' from project
>   'Runner')
>
> ❌  error: No certificate for team '********' matching 'Apple Push
>   Services' found: Select a different signing certificate for
>   CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY, a team that matches your selected certificate, or
>   switch to automatic provisioning. (in target
>   'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' from project 'Runner')

Comment: hi were you able to solve this issue ?

Comment: I had to generate new separate certificates for app and extension